# How can you get Meeko in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How can I obtain the follower Meeko in Skyrim?

Comment: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Meeko

Comment: have you searched this yourself?

Comment: One word: Google

Answer (score 1):

[Meeko](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Meeko), the dog follower can be found at south of [Meeko's Shack](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Meeko%27s_Shack) (south of Solitude, east of Dragon Bridge) by the road. After encountering him on the road, he will run to Meeko's Shack and look at his deceased former master. You can then talk to him, and recruit him as a follower. If you have Hearthfire installed, he can be made a pet, otherwise when dismissed he will return to his shack.

Meeko is a non-humanoid follower, meaning you can have him follow you in addition to a regular follower.